# WP7 Stackpanel/Canvas issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, grid, stackpanel

so I have a question regarding my stackpanel I'm using.

Basically when I keep adding items (expenses/earnings) the into the stackpanel I will eventually be short on navigational space and ultimately the older entries be overwritten.

So at the moment it has a maximum of five entries that can be added and displayed all at one. However If I add another entry/item/expense etc the first entry will be removed/not seen in the stackpanel

So in the picture, as soon as a 6th item is added the 1st item in the list will be removed/not visible

Kind of hard to explain, hope you can help!

[image]

More code:

[pivotItem XAML](http://pastie.textmate.org/4108288)

[ItemsList control XAML](http://pastie.textmate.org/4108371)

Comment: Place your ListBox in the UserControl inside a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: hvala Ivan, the question is how do I allow the scroller to display/hold more data vertically.

Answer (score 0):

put the stackpanel in a scrollviewer. This should allow for automatic resizing as more data is added and you can scroll through it as well